# How to Sort the dataframe by date column in ascending order of 2016-05-06 format?

Tags: python, time-series

I want to sort the table by date of "2016-05-03". I have converted it to a "05/03/2016" format but can't get the date column in proper ascending order(getting the column sorted by the month)

**My code:**

```
date = []
for i, value in enumerate(train_feature_df['search_date']):
    d = dateutil.parser.parse(str(value))
    date.append(d.strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))

train_feature_df['search_date'] = date  
train_feature_df.sort_values(by = 'search_date', ascending = True, inplace = 
True)
```

**Output:**

```
01/03/2016
.
.
01/03/2017
.
.
01/03/2018<br>
```

Kindly suggest alternatives or modification.

Answer (score 0):

This should help.

```
import pandas as pd

train_feature_df = pd.DataFrame({"search_date": ['2017-01-03', '2018-01-03', '2016-01-03']})
train_feature_df['search_date'] = pd.to_datetime(train_feature_df['search_date'])
train_feature_df.sort_values('search_date', ascending = True, inplace=True)
print(train_feature_df)
```

**Output:**

```
  search_date
2  2016-01-03
0  2017-01-03
1  2018-01-03
```

- Use `pd.to_datetime` to convert to datetime object.

Answer (score 0):

Just format dates as `%Y/%m/%d`:

```
a = ['2016-05-03', '2017-12-30', '2018-08-09']
pd.Series(a).sort_values()

0    2016-05-03
1    2017-12-30
2    2018-08-09
dtype: object
```